# What is the previous window called in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I know the current window can be used with "this" but is there anything I can use to call the previous window?

For example I have this code going off when I press a button

```
Buyer_Login BuyerWindow = new Buyer_Login();
            Visibility= Visibility.Hidden;
            BuyerWindow.Show();
```

I need to be able to go back to the first window and I need to close the BuyerWindow and I was going to do it with this.Close();

What can I do to make the first window's visibility visible again?

Comment: `this` is simply a reference to the current instance of the type in which it's used. It has nothing to do with windows and it has nothing to do with any sequence of objects. It's just like if you were in a house and someone said "go to the kitchen" you would know that they meant the kitchen of the house you're in.

Comment: If you want to be able to refer to a specific object of a type then you need to keep a reference to that object. If you're creating a new window and you want that to be able to refer to the current window then you need to pass a reference to the current window into the new window and the new window needs to assign that reference to a field that it can access later. Windows are just objects, like any other, so you treat them just like you would any other object. If a window needs to access an object, you need to pass that object into it.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. You could simply not hide the original window at all, and instead `.ShowDialog()` the second window, which will keep the first window in the background and pass focus back when the second window closes. You could also pass a reference from the first window to the second window, or create an event listener on the first window to listen to the second window's close event, or use a messaging system to send a `ReopenMainWindow` request...

Comment: The previous window will probably be the one in App.Current.Windows collection before the one which is "this".  Likely the one you just opened is the last and the previous the next to last. But it depends exactly what your code does.
  Don't close the first one as it'll be mainwindow and your app will close.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.windows?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0#System_Windows_Application_Windows

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `Window.Closed` event:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var loginWindow = new BuyerLogin();
  loginWindow.Closed += OnBuyerLoginWindowClosed;
  this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  loginWindow.Show();
}

private void OnBuyerLoginWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  => this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

You should consider to show the login window from the App.xaml.cs *before* you show your main window (recommended):

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  var loginWindow = new BuyerLogin();
  bool? dialogResult = loginWindow.ShowDialog();
  if (dialogResult.GetValueOrDefault()) 
  {
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Show();
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application Startup="App_OnStartup">
  <Application.Resources>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of open windows.

```
  App.Current.Windows;
```

It depends on exactly what you're doing opening windows.
If you start up then mainwindow will be [0] in that collection.

Say you then open an instance of window1.

That in turn opens an instance of window2.

There is a bit of a complication if you f5 in visual studio because it opens adorner windows.
Setting that aside for a moment.

When I write code to do what I describe above.
In Window2 I handle content rendered:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wins = App.Current.Windows;
        wins[1].Close();
    }
}
```

That instance of Window1 is closed.

Your new window is very likely the last window in that zero based collection and the previous one the window before that.
You could perhaps search the collection and find index for "this" and subtract one if you're doing more complicated things.

The chances are though, you want to close the window indexed by the count of that collection minus 2. Because it's zero based.

With my exploratory code, window1 closes with this:

```
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wins = App.Current.Windows;
        wins[wins.Count - 2].Close();
    }
```

Personally, I prefer single window apps and switch out the content in part of mainwindow. Leaving navigation buttons etc static in mainwindow.
If you're effectively opening one other window and closing the previous to do things then maybe you could consider a single window app instead.